# Getting error when using getTimer() on FMS

Tags: flash-media-server

I am getting error "No such method found" when using getTimer() on FMS. I wonder, as it's present in AS1.0 also.  Any tips on how to use this function pls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function doesn't exist in Server Side Actionscript, you have to create your own like this:

[Javascript equiv to flash.utils.getTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551788/javascript-equiv-to-flash-utils-gettimer)

Cheers

Tamas

Comment: Ya.. but that's weird. Afterall, it's available in AS1.0

Comment: This is ServerSide ActionScript 1.0, what is not equivalent to ActionScript 1.0